# How are the weights set in the AR and MA?

Tags: time-series, arima, arma

I am studying **ARIMA** models and trying to get a grip of the concept. 
But I cant seem to find anyone motivating the values on the weights.

Consider the following **AR(2)** model below,

$Y_{t} = \mu + \beta Y_{t-1} + \beta_{-1} Y_{t-2} + \epsilon_{t} $

How are the Betas set? They seem to be decreasing since the correlation is lower further back in time (makes sense).

Like; B1 = 0.81, B2 = 0.52 etc...

Are the values found in the ACF/PACF diagrams?

Comment: PACF indicates proper length, once you've decided length (2, in your case) the parameters can be estimated by, say, R, and the method is usually maximum likelihood by default.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure AR model the B's are estimated/suggested using the PACF as starting values. All ARIMA models can be restated as a weighted average of the past.